# ANT war task fails with strange error message

Tags: ant, properties, war

I am trying to create a war file out of an eclipse project using ant
The responsible ant target looks like this

```
<target name="jar" depends="build" description="Erzeugt das WAR File">
    <war destfile="${project.dir.dist}/xyz.jar" webxml="${basedir}/WebRoot/WEB-INF/web.xml" duplicate="fail" basedir="${basedir}">
        <lib dir="${project.dir.dist}" excludesfile="${project.dir.dist}/xyz.jar" />
        <classes dir="${project.dir.bin}" />
        <webinf dir="${basedir}/WebRoot/WEB-INF" excludes="*.class" />
        <metainf dir="${basedir}/WebRoot/META-INF" />
    </war>
</target>
```

And it fails with the following error:
F:\eclipse_workspaces\skyeye\railWeb\build.xml:35: Syntax error in property: ??? ???i8?

Google search turned up only this: http://209.85.135.132/search?q=cache:OrmNOY9EJd0J:teamcity.jetbrains.com/viewLog.html%3Bjsessionid%3D114D52086BAE423B2F69A99B4CFACACD%3FbuildId%3D29573%26tab%3DbuildChangesDiv%26buildTypeId%3Dbt134+ant+war+task+%22Syntax+error+in+property%22&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&client=firefox-a

Can anybody explain, what the heck is going on?

Comment: I encountered the following: build.xml:1139: Syntax error in property: ${��.y

and it was all due to using `excludesFile`. Now I just stay away from `excludesFile`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The propblem was that I used 'excludesFile' assuming it would exclude a single file. Instead ANT tried to parse it as an property file which gets difficult since it actually was a jar file.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to exclude a jar file is given in the [documentation](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/war.html). If anyone face same issue, they can refer to this link.

This example is taken from the documentation, here we are removing `jdbc1.jar` from `lib`

```
Assume the following structure in the project's base directory:

thirdparty/libs/jdbc1.jar
thirdparty/libs/jdbc2.jar
build/main/com/myco/myapp/Servlet.class
src/metadata/myapp.xml
src/html/myapp/index.html
src/jsp/myapp/front.jsp
src/graphics/images/gifs/small/logo.gif
src/graphics/images/gifs/large/logo.gif
then the war file myapp.war created with


<war destfile="myapp.war" webxml="src/metadata/myapp.xml">
  <fileset dir="src/html/myapp"/>
  <fileset dir="src/jsp/myapp"/>
  <lib dir="thirdparty/libs">
    <exclude name="jdbc1.jar"/>
  </lib>
  <classes dir="build/main"/>
  <zipfileset dir="src/graphics/images/gifs"
              prefix="images"/>
</war>


will consist of
WEB-INF/web.xml
WEB-INF/lib/jdbc2.jar
WEB-INF/classes/com/myco/myapp/Servlet.class
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
index.html
front.jsp
images/small/logo.gif
images/large/logo.gif
```